# Is it normal for strstr()?

Tags: c++

## Description:

**Declaration of strstr:**
`char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);`

**Definition of my function:**

```
hostinfo_t *extract_host_from_url(const char *url) {
    /* ... */
    char *scheme_pos = strstr(url, "://");
    /* ... */
}
```

**How I use it:**

```
void rewrite_url(string &url) {
    /* ... */
    hostinfo_t * hostinfo = extract_host_from_url(url.c_str());
    /* ... */
}
```

**Error info:**

> *error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
>
>        char *scheme_pos = strstr(url, "://");*

## Question:

**Where do things go wrong?**

Comment: Are you sure you're writing C? And using a C compiler?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Could you post a [MCVE]

Comment: @Kerrek Compiler is g++

Comment: @CharlesLiuChina: Does that *sound* like a C compiler?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a misunderstanding of which language is being used.

Comment: @KerrekSB Good luck finding that box to tick.

Comment: @KerrekSB no reason to close. The question is well asked and clear. And there is a correct answer below.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Not really. The very first thing that's stated in the question is either an assertion of an obvious falsehood, or an indicator that the OP wants to talk about C.

Comment: @KerrekSB I also don't see a reason to close this, at least not for that reason. It is a clear question, about an issue which might be confusing to a lot of novice C++ and C developers. Now there might be a duplicate, but this is a pretty specific question, so finding a duplicate which actually answers it (instead of providing a wall of text with an implied answer hidden in there) might take a bit of searching.

Comment: My fault, mate, no need to argue about this.

Comment: As an aside: Pass the `std::string` by const reference into `extract_host_from_url`, and then use `const auto scheme_offset = url.find("://");`

Comment: @MartinBonner Yep,I am just curious about the behavior. ^_^

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C++ declaration of `strstr`, as given in `<cstring>` is [overloaded](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strstr)

```
  const char* strstr( const char* str, const char* target );
        char* strstr(       char* str, const char* target );
```

With your set of arguments, you are calling the first function, which is why the return type is `const char*`.